# How do I automatically visualize date in c++ using LibreOffice calc?

Tags: c++, libreoffice-calc

I wrote a program, that simulates the flight of a projectile and prints the x and y coordinates to a .txt file for every delta t (eg.: 0.01s).
Is there some way to import the .txt as a CSV in *LibreOffice calc* and create a x-y-graph to show the flight path **automatically**?
I am able to do it manually but was wondering if it is possible to automate the process.

Comment: To start with, make your program create the CSV directly.

Comment: Since C++ doesn't have graphics support, you will a library or GUI framework that supports graphing or plotting or animation.  See [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities (which is perhaps an indication that the question is Primarily Opinion-Based and should be closed). Regardless, here are 4 ideas using UNO, which is the LibreOffice API.

1. Create a LibreOffice Basic macro that loads a CSV file and generates the graph. In your C++ program, create the CSV file and then do a system call to LibreOffice that runs the macro, for example: `soffice macro:///Standard.Module1.MyMacro` (related: https://superuser.com/questions/1135850/how-do-i-run-a-libreoffice-macro-from-the-command-line-without-the-gui).
2. Create your program as a C++ component that can generate a graph. There are LibreOffice SDK examples at https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#Cpp_examples. C++ SDK examples are generally advanced, without much in the way of a simple tutorial.
3. Python, Basic, or Java are easier to use with LibreOffice in my opinion, at least for beginners. You could write a program in one of these languages that simulates the flight of a projectile and then uses UNO to create the graph.
4. The Python `ctypes` library can load a DLL or SO file. So compile your C++ program into a library file. Then use Python-UNO to call the library file to get the data and generate the graph. LO Basic can load DLL files as well, and Java can with JNI probably, so either of those might also work.

If you don't want to use UNO, there are many libraries designed to generate .ods or .xlsx files, so you may be able to find one for C++ that can create a graph.

One final idea is to create a graph by hand in Calc and set it to use a certain data range. Then run your C++ program and import the CSV data to overwrite that data range. The graph may update automatically, or you might need to refresh to see the results.